# Тип речевой ошибки

Tags: стилистика, семантика

Пожалуйста, определите тип речевой ошибки (плеоназм, тавтология, ошибка в употреблении фразеологизма, ошибка в употреблении деепричастного оборота, употребление слова в несвойственном ему значении, лексическая неполнота высказывания, употребление знаменательных и служебных слов без учета их семантики, клише и штампы, нарушение лексической сочетаемости, неправильное употребление паронимов), отредактируйте предложение.

> Был провозглашен приговор суда.
> Некоторые рабочие допускают дефекты в работе станков.
> К подъезду подъехала тройка лошадей с крытым саквояжем.

Answer (score 2):

1 штамп, но оправданный, так как официально - деловой стиль подразумевает отсутствие двусмысленности и приветствует стандарт.
2 Нарушение лексической сочетаемости: допускают ошибки, недочёты.
3 Употребление слова в несвойственном ему значении: с крытым верхом.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

А мне кажется, что в третьем еще и тавтология присутствует *к подъезду подъехала*. Как-то некрасиво звучит. Наверно, лучше *прискакала* или какой-нибудь другой хороший синоним найти. Что касается второго - это нарушение лексической сочетаемости, правильно будет сказать *некоторые рабочие допускают ошибки (или недочеты) при работе на станках* И *рабочие .. при работе* - опять как "масло масленое". Но, я думаю, тут не в этом суть была. ;-) В первом ошибки нет. Это лексика официально-делового стиля речи. Вполне уместно так сказать. Для какого-либо другого стиля подойдут синонимы *оглашён*, *вынесен*. Можно указать как употребление знаменательных и служебных слов без учета их семантики, если в каждом предложении что-то есть.